# Multiple Separators! How?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules

I've got a field called Name (Entity Reference) that sometimes has 2 values. It would require some kind of Rules I guess. Just not sure how it can be done. I created a taxonomy which has 3 values: "none", "backslash", "and".

So what I wan't to do is if there are 2 values and I've chosen "backslash" the output will be "Name1" / "Name2".

If there are 2 values and I've chosen "and" the output will be "Name1" & "Name2".

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a Rules problem. (yet)
To re-state the issue: you are trying to output display the values, and use a delimiter when there are multiple values.  Correct?

If so, where is the display taking place, of for example, "Name1" / "Name2"
Is this in a Node, View, Module ... or elsewhere?  Please be as specific as possible.

A Rules problem would sound like "for Trigger X I expect Action Y to take place".

Comment: Yes, that's correct. 
The field Name is being used both in a View and a Node (Panels).

Comment: Okay, I should've asked but presumably this is D7; There are several options how to handle.  One good place to start will be taking a look at the field_delimiter module [https://www.drupal.org/project/field_delimiter] which I know handles this scenario and depends on [https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_settings]  ... there is also this prior answer that shows the very important "multiple field settings" area expanded and addresses this issue in node display: [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51327/changing-the-field-separator-for-multivalue-fields]

Comment: I can't see any option for having different delimiters? I would need at least 3 different that I can choose from with each Node.

Comment: I need the ability to have individual delimiters on each field on every individual node. Is this possible with Field Delimiter? I have only found away to set delimiter per field.

Comment: So you want per-field AND per-node. Seems like that would go beyond the existing module, which as you noted is per field.  You could update the existing module the features you're looking for, and contrib back... or create a new separate module that does exactly what you need.  This does seem like you're going to need some coding done.

Comment: Yes it appears to be that way unfortunately. The thing is that I need to use the separators in both 2 different Views and Node Panels. If it was only in Nodes then I could have done some CSS targeting particular Nodes. Anyone got a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about node display then it sounds like problem for the [Custom Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module.

You can define a formatter in code that iterates through all values and joins them with '/' and then use this formatter in your node display settings (additionally to the default options)

Comment: Looking at some videos of the module it looks nice but...well then there's another problem. I don't know PHP or Javascript coding so it don't help me much. :/